# How can I stop text wrap in Tab.Screen react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to show the text in a row without wrapping the text, how can I achieve that?

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs'
import React from 'react'
import Overview from '../Overview/Overview'
import BirdsEyesView from '../BirdsEyeView/BirdsEyesView'
import Docs from '../Docs/Docs'
import Inbox from '../Inbox/Inbox'
import Rounds from '../Rounds/Rounds'

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()
const DataRounds = () => {
```

render the data here

```
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                tabBarActiveTintColor: 'blue',
                tabBarLabelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 13,
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    margin: 0,
                    padding: 0,
                    textTransform: 'none',
                },

                tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
                    borderBottomColor: 'blue',
                    borderBottomWidth: 2,
                },

                tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'black',
                tabBarStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#E7F6F2',
                },
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Overview"
                component={Overview}
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Overview',
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Bird'sEyeView"   // I want make this title in a row without wrapping
                component={BirdsEyesView}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: `Bird's Eye View` }}
                style={styles.text}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Docs"
                component={Docs}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Docs' }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Inbox"
                component={Inbox}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Inbox' }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Rounds"
                component={Rounds}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Rounds' }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

styling

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: { marign: 10 },
})
export default DataRounds
```

[image: image of the UI]

In the image, I want the Bird's eye view in a row without wrapping.
Please let  me know how can I achieve this, it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing some of the style props of the navigator and experimenting with the width. For example:

```
<Tab.Screen
   name="Bird'sEyeView"
   component={BirdsEyesView}
   options={{
     tabBarLabel: `Bird's Eye View`,
     tabBarItemStyle​: { width: 150 }
   }}
   style={styles.text}
/>
```

You could also try changing `tabBarLabelStyle​`, or as a last resort, passing a custom tab component in `tabBarButton`.

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

Comment: Thanks Abe for the suggestion, it works with tabBarItemStyle

Comment: tabBarItemStyle: { width: 'auto' },

Comment: great!  if it helped please feel free to accept the answer, or if you solved it your own way feel free to answer and accept that!